# Conditional post thumbnail based on logged status and post tag

Tags: post-thumbnails, user-roles, archives

I'd like to show different post thumbnails in archive.php and category.php like this:

- user logged out & post has tag "private" -> shows a "default-private" image
- user logged in & post has tag "private" -> show the actual featured image attached to the post
- no matter the logged in status and all other posts with no "private" tag, if no image set -> show "default" image

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in() && has_tag('private')) { ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-login.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>

    <?php } else {                  

         // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail('news-thumb', 
                       array('class' => 'news-thumb'));
                } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> 
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                </a>
<?php } ?>
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you have to use the below logic to handle the above conditions, it will work.

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() && has_tag('private')) { ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-login.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>

<?php } else if( is_user_logged_in() && has_tag('private') ) {                  
    // show the actual featured image
    // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('news-thumb', 
        array('class' => 'news-thumb'));
    }
    //if you want to show the default image if featured image is not attached you can add here in else 
}else{
    ?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
        </a>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works almost perfectly. Still doesn't address the 3rd condition: if user is logged in or not logged in, no matter what the tag. I wanted to add that to the second statement but there's again something wrong with the syntaxis:

Comment: `else if( is_user_logged_in() && has_tag('private')) || (is_user_logged_in() && !has_tag() ) { `

Comment: I have given you logic how you should write it. You can change the logic according to your scenario.

Comment: I did. I came up with the final statement. Thank you

Comment: Great to know that 